# What to use Flush Mode 'Auto' or 'Commit'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

As my title described, I am using hibernate `Auto` flush mode mechanism in my application. So, when I change any data in a hibernate persistent object, it reflects automatically in the database. I don't want this. So I found a solution to use FlushMode `Commit` instead.

So here is my actual question:

- Is it better to use `Commit` flush mode instead of `Auto`? and
- What is the meaning of this statement from the documentation?

  > The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order
  >   to ensure that queries never return stale state.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html

Comment: Check the link http://www.cpe.ku.ac.th/~plw/oop/e_book/hibernate_in_action.pdf and scroll to page 5.1.3 Flushing the Session. Cheers.,

Comment: What you are looking for is transactions.  You should (in general) be using transactions to define when things are committed to the database as opposed to manually flushing the session: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions?_sscc=t

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hibernate (and JPA) are designed to automatically detect and persist changes to persistent objects to the database. There is no "save" operation.

If you don't want things saved, you should use detached objects. Either use a `StatelessSession` to load them, or call detach after loading your objects. This removes them from the monitoring that will automatically save them.

Don't mess with the flush settings, it will just give you headaches later.

Comment: Can you specify what kind of headache it might give you? We're looking at this as a solution and want to know if it might not be the right solution.

Comment: Let's say that you have a write that causes an error. Further delaying flushes means a bigger you might not find out about the error until several queries later. Hope you didn't want to inform a user!

Or let's say that your read-only application suddenly needs to change to keep track of what users are browsing - for metrics, reporting, or auditing purposes. Now you have to revisit every single query in your app.

Those are just a couple of examples off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks @Barrett. Those are exactly the kind of issues we found. :-(

Comment: What are em.persist() and em.merge() then? Aren't they "save" operations?

Comment: @MS13 the image in "entity state transitions" might help you. https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-save-merge-saveorupdate-whats-difference-one-use/ The OP said "change any data in a hibernate persistent object", so my answer is in the context of "managed" phase objects. persist and save take unmanaged objects and make them managed. Merge takes a detached object and makes it managed. Managed objects have their changes persisted automatically - you don't need to call one of those methods to save. It's true but confusing to folks used to working with SQL or JDBC.

Comment: it looks like a nasty side-effect to me

Answer (score 8):

> is it better to use Commit flush mode instead of Auto

When your application uses queries the `FlushMode.COMMIT` will most likely perform better because it will not flush session before each query. I know that per javadoc it should flush session only when necessary but from my experience FlushMode.COMMIT performs even better in read-only sessions. Auto-flush doesn't mean that any change to the persistent object is immediately posted to the database.

> what is meaning of below statement specified in document
>
> The Session is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state.

As I've written above when FlushMode.AUTO (default) is used it will flush session before every query (HQL, Criteria, SQL query) made to the database to make sure results will contain all entities added within current session.

Comment: FYI to readers, this answer is outright contrary to the Hibernate documentation. https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html

Comment: I first read the documentation and then came here, and I think this answer clearly explains what is meant in the documentation. Though, "The Session is sometimes flushed ..." does not mean it is flushed before every query. The meaning of "sometimes" is explained here http://java.dzone.com/articles/dark-side-hibernate-auto-flush

Comment: Updated link to @BahattinUngormus answer:  https://dzone.com/articles/dark-side-hibernate-auto-flush