# Calling a Native Query in the same request life cycle as a JPA managed query causes automatic persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm sure this is a feature, but I would appreciate any pointers/help on the issue.

I'm using Spring (Boot) / JPA (Hibernate) stack.

If I query for an entity (called Homes) using JPA, and increment a Calendar field

```
homeInstance.getListedDate().add(Calendar.DATE, 1), for example
```

with no intention of saving this change back to the database (it's only for quick intermediary calculations as the several routines run on a list of these entities).

Then I call a nativequery using an injected EntityManager bean.

```
@Autowired
EntityManager em;
...
Query nvqry = em.createNativeQuery(...)
nvqry.getResultList()
```

Doing this automatically persists the changes made to the entity above (which were never supposed to be persisted.

Is there a way to disable this feature without losing the in-memory changes? I manually persist anything I want using the repository, and as such a whole session persistence is useless for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's related to the hibernate [FlushMode](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html). If you haven't modified the default configuration, this will be likely set to `FlushMode.AUTO`.

To alter this behavior you have to provide an `EntityManagerFactory` bean.

In the configuration pojo you can declare something like this:

```
@Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            final DataSource dataSource,
            final JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPersistenceUnitName("domainPC");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(getClass().getPackage().getName());
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        //and here is your flushMode set.
        jpaProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.flushMode", "COMMIT");
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was enlightening and pointed me to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149876/what-to-use-flush-mode-auto-or-commit) after a bit of searching. You think I should use detach instead? What would be minimal impact on existing code?

Comment: it's up to you to decide which strategy to use. I prefer to explicitly control the DB state by calling save(), so I set the flushMode to COMMIT or MANUAL

Comment: Just a clarification. By "save()" you mean the repository's save? Ex: homeRepo.save(homeEntityInstance); ?

Comment: @BKaun, yes. That's homeReop.save(entity)