# Hibernate merge deleting records

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate is managing class X. Our code loads an array of X and when I submit changes via update(), I get the dreaded NonUniqueObjectException on the second instance of X, whether or not I made any changes to it. merge() doesn't throw the exception, but instead deletes all but two of my array. ??? I've searched SO and other sites and they all say that update(), or saveOrUpdate(), will handle the processing, but it ain't so. No idea what would cause merge() to delete anything.

Comment: Can you add code how you are merging or updating entity...

Comment: getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().setFlushMode(FlushMode.COMMIT);

getHibernateTemplate().merge(entity);

getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per code which you have added 
Transaction is maintained by Hibernate Automatically.
Any specific reason Why are you setting FlushMode to Commit?

Ref [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/FlushMode.html) for FlushMode. In your case it will be called only on Transaction commit which is done automatically.

As per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149876/what-to-use-flush-mode-auto-or-commit) its not good idea to play with FlishMode

Try this instead - we are telling session.merge instead hibernatetemplate.merge

```
Session hibSession = getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
hibSession.merge(myObject);
hibSession.flush();
```

Comment: Thanks, Ashish. I'll give it a try.